# cannot understand the output for switch statement for input 3

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I am not getting this..please help me find the way of evaluation of this code.
(input is 3)

```
int a = 9, b;

scanf("%d", &b);

switch(a+b)
{
    case 3:
        a+= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a + b;
    default:
        a-= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a - b;
    case 9:
        a+= a * 3 - (a-b);
        b = a/b;
        break;
    case 5:
        a%=b;
}
printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n",a,b);
```

the output for input 3 is(actual) :

33
5

shouldn't it be like this following two's(expected) :

9
6

Comment: Your `switch` statement is missing `break`s after most of the `case` blocks, so multiple cases will be executed (including the `default` case since `a+b` (12) is not one of the specified cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `break` statement at the end of the `3` or `default` cases, so the code **falls through** to the following cases until a `break` is encountered or until the end of the `switch` is reached.

Be sure to add a `break` after every case.  Also, the `default` case should go at the bottom by convention:

```
switch(a+b)
{
    case 3:
        a+= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a + b;
        break;
    case 9:
        a+= a * 3 - (a-b);
        b = a/b;
        break;
    case 5:
        a%=b;
        break;
    default:
        a-= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a - b;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it isn't working is that after `default:` finishes, there is no `break;` so control continues into the code for `case 9`. Here is it fixed:

```
int a = 9, b;

scanf("%d", &b);

switch(a+b)
{
    case 3:
        a+= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a + b;
        break;
    case 5:
        a%=b;
        break;
    case 9:
        a+= a * 3 - (a-b);
        b = a/b;
        break;
    default:
        a-= b * 2 - (a-b);
        b = a - b;
        break;
}
printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n",a,b);
```

Also, it is better for readability to order the cases in some way, not just randomly; `default` also always goes at the bottom.

Comment: Most people put default as the last case, but there is no requirement to do so.